# openBinaryFile: does not exist when executing pandoc in Gitlab CI bash script

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci, pandoc

I am getting this error:

`pandoc: sh: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

when trying to build some assets with Pandoc in a Gitlab CI bash script.

[I have a repo, Finnito/Science,](https://gitlab.com/Finnito/science) that is serving a Gitlab Pages site using Hugo. I am trying to set up a Gitlab CI pipeline to build my HTML slides and PDFs docs from my Markdown source when I commit to the repo so that I don't have to build them locally.

I have been trying out different Docker images of pandoc but decided [pandoc/latex](https://hub.docker.com/r/pandoc/latex) is my best bet because it's "official" and built on Alpine which is nice and lightweight. But I can't seem to make heads or tails of this error.

I have tried various different incantations for pandoc but they don't seem to work.

My Gitlab CI job looks like this:

```
assets:
  image: pandoc/latex
  script:
    - chmod +x ci-build.sh
    - sh ci-build.sh
```

and my `ci-build.sh` script looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

modulesToBuild=(
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/10sci/5-fire-and-fuels"
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/10scie/6-geology"
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/11sci/4-mechanics"
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/11sci/5-genetics"
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/12phy/2-mechanics"
    "/builds/Finnito/science/content/12phy/3-electricity"
)

for i in "${modulesToBuild[@]}"; do

    # Navigate to the directory.
    cd $i

    # Build the HTML slides and
    # PDFs for all markdown docs.
    for filename in markdown/*.md; do
        file=${filename##*/}
        name=${file%%.*}
        pandoc/latex pandoc -s --mathjax -i -t revealjs "markdown/$name.md" -o "$name.html"
        pandoc/latex pandoc "markdown/$name.md" -o "$name.pdf" --pdf-engine=pdflatex
    done
done
```

Honestly, I'm just pretty lost with how to successfully call pandoc within the Docker container. I am very new to this and it all makes very little sense!

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use `$PWD` before the `pandoc/latex` command? With docker you can run try running your it locally on your pc.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have tried using it with and without the $PWD but it gives me the same error each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image has `/usr/bin/pandoc` set as an [entry point](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). This means that one doesn't has to specify the `pandoc` command when running the container; providing a command it will cause pandoc to try to read an input file with the name of the given command, which causes the error you are seeing.

For a while, images used a custom entrypoint script which tried to detect if a different binary should be executed. But this was reverted as it proved unreliable and confusing.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Is there a way I can call pandoc from within my script like I want to do? Or do I need to do something like fork the docker image and remove the ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: To be honest, IDK: I haven't really used gitlab ci so far. You could probably try to define your image as `image: {name: pandoc/latex, entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]}`

Comment: Ah that's definitely it. 

```assets:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: pandoc/latex:2.6
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  script:
    - apk add bash
    - apk add zip
    - chmod +x ci-build.sh
    - ./ci-build.sh
```